# Handling XSLT file names c#

Tags: c#, xslt, filenames, xslcompiledtransform

Wondering how to best deal with a problem I am having with xsltransform. Long story short, everything works in my test environment, but it crashes when I run it on the server due to the filenames it tries to deal with, which are output from another program, over which I have no control.

For example. "4Copy (2) of Fed_Around_Six__TFVC020-12.mov.xml" a simple @ would solve this, but it's actually running on a service, and this service gets all files of that type in the directory and processes them one by one.

```
string[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, Filetype);
```

I keep the file name variable in:

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filepaths[i]);
```

But the method I use for the transform:

```
myXslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
myXslTransform.Transform(filename,OutputFileName);
```

Only accepts `(String, String)` and thus when it sees "4Copy (2) of Fed_Around_Six__TFVC020-12.mov.xml" it has a heart attack and cuts it off.

I was thinking save the original name, rename, remove whitespace, transform, and rename back. But I think there is a smarter way to handle it out there, just not sure where to look. Is there a way of telling C# to handle a variable as a literal? Or a different transform method that accepts these weird filenames with very bad naming conventions?

Any insight that helps would be great!

The error & exception message I recieve from the Eventvwr is

Cannot Translate 
\\9g031\Export\4Copy (2) of Fed_Around_Six__TFVC020-12.mov.xml

OutputName = \\9g031\Export\done\4Copy (2) of Fed_Around_Six__TFVC020-12.mov.xml

XSL LOC = C:\CXS.xsl

System.IO.IOException: The specified path is invalid.

```
                private void PreformTranslation(FileInfo FileName, String OutputFileName , String result)
    {
        try
        {
            XslCompiledTransform myXslTransform;
            myXslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            myXslTransform.Load(XSLname);
            EventLog.WriteEntry(FileName.ToString(), OutputFileName);
            myXslTransform.Transform(FileName.Name,OutputFileName);
            EventLog.WriteEntry("TranslationComplete");


            if (File.Exists(path + result))
            {
                MoveVideoFiles(path + result, outputPath + result);
            }
           // Rename(OutputFileName, FileName, Out);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            EventLog.WriteEntry("Cannot Translate " + FileName + " OutputName = " + OutputFileName + " \r\n"+
                "XSL LOC = " + XSLname + "\r\n" + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're getting an execption or error, please post it.

Comment: `"4Copy (2) of Fed_Around_Six__TFVC020-12.mov.xml"` _is_ a string, and is also a valid filename. Your exception has nothing to do with types of arguments or `@`. Please tell what exactly you mean by "has a heart attack".

Comment: This might seem a bit obvious, but I presume there's something in between instantiating the `XslCompiledTransform` and doing the transform? i.e., loading the stylesheet into it? If not, I think that might be your problem.

Comment: Also, can you check on what line you get the exception? It looks like it may not be the call to Transform.

Comment: You guys where right , during the transform It is not passing the right file name - its looking in windows/system32/ filename , for the file!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default directory when running a service is something like "windows/system32" and this isn't the directory of the executable.

This is probably the reason the XML file isn't found.

Comment: The xml path was right , but i was passing it the wrong filename for it to translate , the service looked in system32 dir because i was not passing it a fully qualified name instead of Filename.Name it should have been Filename.toString(). Thanks .

Comment: @user685590: Yes, this is what I am saying. In Windows a "regular" exe has as default (current) directory the one the exe file is residing in. Any relative filepaths are resolved off this default directory. The default directory for a windows service exe is "windows\system32" and any program expecting its relative filepaths to be resolved off the directory the executable resides in -- is in trouble.